# How to get the most sold Product in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given a table **products**

| pid | name |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Milk |
| 456 | Tea |
| 789 | Cake |
| ... | ... |

and a table **sales**

| stamp | pid | units |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14:54 | 123 | 3 |
| 15:02 | 123 | 9 |
| 15:09 | 456 | 1 |
| 15:14 | 456 | 1 |
| 15:39 | 456 | 2 |
| 15:48 | 789 | 12 |
| ... | ... | ... |

How would I be able to get the **product(s) with the most sold units**?
My goal is to run a `SELECT` statement that results in, for this example,

| pid | name |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Milk |
| 789 | Cake |

because the sum of sold units of both those products is 12, the maximum value (greater than 4 for Tea, despite there being more sales for Tea).

I have the following query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT products.pid, products.name
FROM sales
    INNER JOIN products ON sale.pid = products.pid
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT pid, SUM(units) as sum_units
        FROM sales
        GROUP BY pid
    ) AS total_units ON total_units.pid = sales.pid
WHERE total_units.sum_units IN (
    SELECT MAX(sum_units) as max_units
    FROM (
        SELECT pid, SUM(units) as sum_units
        FROM sales
        GROUP BY pid
    ) AS total_units
);
```

However, this seems very long, confusing, and inefficient, even repeating the sub-query to obtain `total_units`, so I was wondering if there was a better way to accomplish this.

How can I simplify this? Note that I can't use `ORDER BY SUM(units) LIMIT 1` in case there are multiple (i.e., >1) products with the most units sold.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Postgres 13 it has supported *with ties* so your query can be simply this:

```
select p.pId, p.name
from sales s
join products p on p.pid = s.pid
group by p.pId, p.name
order by Sum(units) desc
fetch first 1 rows with ties;
```

See [demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f5d677e678529e00f31d795ca80a371f)

Answer (score 0):

Solution for your problem:

```
WITH cte1 AS
(
 SELECT s.pid, p.name,
 SUM(units) as total_units
 FROM sales s
 INNER JOIN products p
 ON s.pid = p.pid
 GROUP BY s.pid, p.name
),
cte2 AS
(
 SELECT *,
 DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY total_units DESC) as rn
 FROM cte1
)
SELECT pid,name
FROM cte2
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY pid;
```

Working example: [db_fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=22ec6089499479f9e1f3c8fd42583d9e)